# i have installed oracle 64 bit client on my laptop ..toad isn't working ..and is there a utility like SQL*Plus the older version?

Tags: user-interface, installation, oracle11g, toad

sqlplus command line utility is working fine but i need to copy commands edit them rerun them command  prompt is little bit of a hindrance for that matter ..i have downloaded the sql instant client 32 bit and don't know how to proceed further in the installation of it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Install TOAD? Edit commands in SQL*Plus? Install instant client?

Comment: all i want is a client other than the command promt(sql plus) i tried installing toad it installed properly but i get an error when connecting to the server is 'Cannot load OCI DLL: c:\app\Ram\product\11.1.0\db_1\BIN\oci.dll'.and I'm using oracle 11g

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @vadim k. ok sorry but i need to resolve the issue

Comment: Try [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your installation of the client is not complete.  Uninstall and try installing the oracle client again.

As for a gui sqlplus, it is now called sql developer.  It can be downloaded [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html).

Comment: how do i know if the installation of the client is complete or not ?

the command prompt sqlplus is working fine.there isnt any gui installed

Comment: I have seen a few time where the oci.dll is missing which will cause issues with most tools.  Looking for that file is the way I have done it.